# Check series for uniform convergence on real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{1 + n} \frac{x^2 \sin x}{1 + n^5x^4}, E = \mathbb{R} $$
I tried to determine convergent subseries and something limited to use Abel - Dirichlet test, I can't find series that fit here.

Comment: "I tried to determine convergent subseries and something limited to use some tests, but failed." - and yet you didn't see fit to include those efforts in your post?

Comment: I think you can put $x^2\sin x$ outside the sum without needing any convergence condition.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on a set $E,$ then we must have $\sup_E|f_n| \to 0.$ Is that true here?